# Do you pray Sunnah and Fard separately?

Tags: salat, practical-islam

Ok, it is a bit complex for me. Suppose you are praying for Fajr and you have got 2 rakat sunnah and 2 fard. How do you pray them? All in one go or do you pray sunnah first by making Niyah and in the end you give salam left and right and then you stand up make a new niyah for praying fard?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

They are prayed separately, you pray sunnah first, do taslim and then start the fard.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your example if you prayed two raka'as sunnah and two raka'as fard in one go you would have prayed four raka'as which doesn't correspond to neither of both.
Each prayer must be prayed for itself with a own niyyah (intention) and starts with takbeer and ends with tasleem.

> The key to prayer is purification; its
>    beginning is takbir and its end is taslim.  ([Sunan Abu Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/61) and [Jam'i At-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/90))

And for our example we may find in a hadith:

> ... Then Bilal pronounced the Adhan (i.e. call for the Fajr prayer). The Prophet (ﷺ) **then offered two rak`at** (Sunna) prayer and went out (to the Mosque) and **offered the (compulsory congregational) Fajr prayer**. ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/urn/178990))

which shows the practice as described above.

Comment: how about when you have three rakat fard? When do you recite the shahadah? on the second or on the third or on both?

Comment: @BurreIfort that's a totally different question and should be asked separately.

Answer (score 0):

They are prayed seperately, Sunnah starts from niyyah for fard, then Takbir to Salam/Tasleem. Then after tasleem you stand up, make niyyah for fard, then Takbir to salam/Tasleem. And let's say as an example suppose you are praying for fajr, that's two Rakat sunnah and two rakat fard. If you prayed them in one go it would be four rak'aats, which wouldn't correspond to neither of both.